# How to parse simple JSON file which contains lists and nested objects

Tags: json, list, flutter, dart, nested

I have copied my JSON data to local file in flutter and using it as assets.

I need to parse data from the JSON file and get a list of Text widget

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'JsonParsing.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeState createState() => new HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Some App"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future:
                DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('jsons/data.json'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              Map myData = json.decode(snapshot.data);
              var datas = User.fromJson(myData);
              print(myData.length);
              print(datas);

              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {

                  return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(myData[index]['table_menu_list'][index]['category_dishes']
                        [index]['dish_name']),
                  ));
                },
                itemCount: myData == null ? 0 : myData.length,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code gives an error " type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map';"

**AnyOne help to parse the data of dish_name as a list of text in my app**
There are so many list of dish_name in that JSON. I want to get all the list name in text widget

JSON file link: [JsonLinkoffoodData](https://www.mocky.io/v2/5dfccffc310000efc8d2c1ad)

Answer (score 0):

Check this page:

[Flutter Documentation - JSON Generating Code for Nested Classes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#generating-code-for-nested-classes)

Comment: what if my json data contains both lists and nested data. The above documentation only provides info. for nested classes. my json data contain list inside nested classes

Answer (score 0):

```
  with: print(myData.length);
  print(myData);
```

These are the output:

I/flutter (16203): 1
I/flutter (16203): [{restaurant_id: 1010000001, restaurant_name: UNI Resto Cafe, restaurant_image: http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/1010000001.jpg, table_id: 1, table_name: Riyadh-Table 01, branch_name: UNI Resto Cafe-Riyadh, nexturl: http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/10/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en, table_menu_list: [{menu_category: Salads and Soup, menu_category_id: 11, menu_category_image: http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/Item/ItemGroup_11.jpg, nexturl: http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/20/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuCat=11&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en, category_dishes: [{dish_id: 100000001, dish_name: Spinach Salad, dish_price: 7.95, dish_image: http://restaurants.unicomerp.net//images/Restaurant/1010000001/Item/Items/100000001.jpg, dish_currency: SAR, dish_calories: 15, dish_description: Fresh spinach, mushrooms, and hard-boiled egg served with warm bacon vinaigrette, dish_Availability: true, dish_Type: 2, nexturl: http://snapittap